BigQuery `load_table_from_dataframe` in a transaction?
I have multiple data pipelines which perform the following actions in BigQuery:

Load data into a table using the BQ Python client's load_table_from_dataframe method.
Execute a BigQuery merge SQL statement to update/insert that data to another table.
Truncate the original table to keep it empty for the next pipeline.

How can I perform these actions in a transaction to prevent pipelines from interfering with one another?
I know I can use BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION as shown in the docs but my insertion using load_table_from_dataframe does not allow me to include my own raw SQL, so I'm unsure how to implement this part in a transaction.
Additionally BigQuery cancels transactions that conflict with one another. Ideally I want each transaction to queue rather than fail on conflict. I question whether there is a better approach to this.

What about using load_table_from_dataframe to load the data into a TEMP table and then merge from there.  I'm not sensing that a load table can be embraced by a transaction.  But maybe, loading into a temp table and then using the temp table as a source opens up new options.

You can't load into a TEMP table with the Python client unfortunately

Oh my ... I hadn't realized that.  Many thanks for pointing that out.  I did find the following ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295881/python-bigquery-temporary-table
This seems to imply we can create an "equivalent" to a TEMP table using the BigQuery Python client.   With that in mind ... maybe we can create a "temp like table" and then use load_table_from_dataframe to populate the data in the existing table.

Great suggestion, this is what I landed on as well since posting this question! I like it

you can also consider using Pub/Sub, sending messages when ever one process is complete to trigger the next action.
